# spring social twitter isConnected issue (RevokedAuthorizationException)

Tags: grails, twitter, spring-social

I'm using Grails and the spring social twitter plugin. Everything works fine except in one case:

I check if the user is connected to twitter via this piece of code

```
connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class)
```

while this works fine if I authorize the app in twitter, it still gives TRUE when I revoke the authorization. How can I make the function check if it's connected and if the user didn't revoke the authorization ? (right now it gives true, and I have a RevokedAuthorizationException  just after when trying to use the API).

**UPDATE:**
I tried to catch the RevokedAuthorizationException in order to redirect the user to twitter, it works BUT now I have a weird behavior: if a user revoke once the authorization, even if he then authorizes the app, it keeps giving a RevokedAuthorizationException ?!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because I haven't tried it yet, but I think you can use the test() method of the Connection API (http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/serviceprovider.html)